# Displaying Monthly Sales in a Donut Chart

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a dynamic dashboard where a donut chart would show total amount of sales by month name. For the query I've used:

```
$sales_by_month = "SELECT MONTHNAME(pay_time) as mname,
                sum(amount) as total_sales
                FROM aamarpay
                GROUP BY MONTH(pay_time)";
                 

$res_sales_by_month = mysqli_query($conn, $sales_by_month);
```

After that I'm using a template from google chart to display the data. But the chart is only showing one month of data instead of multiple month data I have on my database.

Here's the code to fetch the data:

```
function drawChart() {
    <?php
    while($rows_sales = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_sales_by_month)):
        $month = $rows_sales['mname'];
        $total_sales = $rows_sales['total_sales'];
    ?>
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Totals Sales'], 
      ['<?php echo $month; ?>', '<?php echo $total_sales; ?>'  ]
    
      ]);
      <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Here's how it shows up:
[donut chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvLOW.jpg)

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're close, but you are pushing 1 row of data at a time because you're in a loop and that row is overwriting the previous row. You need to build up your entire array in PHP and then call `arrayToDataTable`. One option is instead of using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and a loop, call `mysqli_fetch_all` and pass that array to `arrayToDataTable`

Comment: I've just tried your method. But it did not work.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the updated code, pls?

Comment: I've found the solution. Posted as an answer here please check.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Month', 'Totals Sales'], 
      <?php
      while($row_sales=mysqli_fetch_array($res_sales_by_month))
      {
          echo "['".$row_sales["mname"]."', ".$row_sales["total_sales"]."],";
      }
      ?>
      ]);
```